# Можно ли это назвать нормальной реализацией std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, инспекция-кода

Обновил

```
template <class T>
class My_unique_ptr
{
private:
    T * ptr;
public:
    My_unique_ptr(T * s_ptr=nullptr) : ptr(s_ptr)
    {
    }

~My_unique_ptr()
{
    delete ptr;
}

My_unique_ptr(const My_unique_ptr& value) = delete;             // запретили конструктор копирования

My_unique_ptr(My_unique_ptr&& s_ptr) : ptr(s_ptr.ptr)
{
    s_ptr.ptr = nullptr;
}


My_unique_ptr& operator=(const My_unique_ptr& value) = delete;  // запретили копирование

My_unique_ptr& operator=(My_unique_ptr&& s_ptr)
{
    if (&s_ptr == this)
        return *this;

    delete ptr ;

    ptr = s_ptr.ptr;
    s_ptr.ptr = nullptr;

    return *this;
}

operator bool() const { if (ptr) return true; else return false; }
T* operator->() const { return ptr == ; }
T& operator*() const 
{ 
    assert(ptr && "is nullptr");
    return *ptr; 
}

void swap(My_unique_ptr& obj) noexcept
{
    T* temp{ std::move(obj.ptr) };
    obj.ptr = ptr;
    ptr = temp;
}

void reset(T* obj = nullptr) noexcept
{
    if (ptr)
        delete ptr;
    if (obj)
        ptr = obj;
}

T * release() noexcept
{
    T * old_ptr = ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
    return old_ptr;
}

T * get() noexcept
{
    return ptr;
}

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `operator=` происходит утечка памяти.

В `operator*` нет даже ассерта на разыменование нулевого указателя.

Нет варианта работы с указателем, выделенным при помощи new[].

Нет варианта предоставления пользовательской функции освобождения ресурсов.

Нет поддержки noexcept.

Comment: А можно немного подробнее по поводу пунктов 1,4,5?

Comment: @Artem.rtv Куда ж подробней? При выполнении `ptr = nullptr;`  утекает память, на которую указывал `ptr`. В unique_ptr функция освобождения памяти передается как параметр шаблона, а тут почему-то захаркожено `delete(ptr);`. `noexcept` нигде не используется, хотя мог бы.

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать

Comment: Что скажете теперь? если можно :) Поддержку new[] пока не добавил, с этим позже буду разбираться. Остальное вроде добавил (возможно, разве что без 4 пункта). есть у него еще метод get_deleter, который я пока не осилил..

Comment: @Artem.rtv Ну `return ptr == ;` - это что такое. После `reset` может оставаться битый указатель. `noexcept` по-прежнему не везде используется. Не перемещающий конструктор и оператор bool должны быть `explicit`.